# Is it possible to do outdoor navigation using only GPS & IMU, without any map? If yes then please suggest how?

Tags: navigation, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to achieve autonomous outdoor navigation on the road. I have a 2d-LIDAR, GPS & IMU as available sensors data to the robot. I am getting fused data of GPS, IMU & Odom, I also have the waypoint(in UTM) of the road on the road which I wish to do autonomous navigation, but I don't have a map. How will the robot plan it's a path to destination i.e I mean how planners will work without a map?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/345060/is-it-possible-to-do-outdoor-navigation-using-only-gps-&-imu,-without-any-map?-if-yes-then-please-suggest-how?/) by [ShyamGanatra](https://answers.ros.org/users/38099/shyamganatra/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2020-02-25

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pavel92](https://answers.ros.org/users/32610/pavel92/) on 2020-02-26**:
You can still perform navigation without a map. With the absence of pointcloud sensors you just cant do obstacle avoidance since the ROS navigation (the costmap plugins specifically) stack requires pointcloud data in order to add obstacles on the costmap so that the planners can plan a valid path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you have a good GPS and for your demo/application you don’t expect to lose a GPS fix, that sounds reasonable from a first-look perspective.

You still have data coming in about your environment. You can keep a local buffer of data for obstacle avoidance but if you have waypoints, you have a path. Another form of global planning should be largely redundant.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2020-02-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0